# Какие различия между методами edit и update, create и store в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

В Laravel при использовании контроллера ресурсов вызываются различные методы, в зависимости от метода с помощью которого был передан запрос.

Меня интересуют методы update и edit.
Update - в переводе с англ обновить.
Edit - редактировать.

Допустим у нас есть форма учётных данных пользователя которые он может менять. Нажимая кнопку сохранить вызывается метод update и запись в базе данных обновляется. Но тогда зачем нужен метод edit? Какие различия между ними?

Такой же вопрос у меня по отношению к методам store и create.

Comment: *Create* - отображение формы для создания сущности, *Edit* - отображение формы редактирования сущности.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel CRUD

---

**index** - Вывод всех записей

```
public function index()
{
    // Получение всех записей
    return view('index', compact());
}
```

---

**create** - Показ формы создания

```
public function create()
{
   return view('create');
}
```

---

**show** - Показ определенной записи

```
public function show($id)
{
    // Получение записи по ID
    return view('show', compact());
}
```

---

**store** - Создание ресурса

```
public function store(Request $request) {}
```

---

**edit** - Показ формы редактирования

```
public function edit($id)
{
    // Получение записи по ID
    return view('edit', compact());
}
```

---

**update** - Обновление ресурса

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {}
```

---

**delete** - Удаление записи

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $collection = User::find($id);
    $collection->delete();

    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Row has been deleted!!');
}
```

Итого, мы имеем ресурсный компонент laravel который включает в себя:

- **index** - вывод всех записей
- **show** - показ определенной записи
- **create** - форма создания записи
- **store** - обработка создания записи
- **edit** - форма редактирования записи
- **update** - обработка обновления редактируемой записи
- **destroy** - удаление записи